# SQLite3 / python: Results differ when selecting from VIEW instead of TABLE

Tags: python, sqlite

So I was refactoring some of my code to use SQL views instead of repeating the same query all over the place. And suddenly, some of the unit tests start failing with messages that queries don't have all required attributes.

So, knowing that the VIEW really should return the same structure (just with a few filters), this was weird. I was able to reproduce it with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

db.execute('CREATE TABLE foo(id INT PRIMARY KEY, alpha TEXT, beta TEXT)')
db.execute('CREATE VIEW  foo_view AS SELECT * FROM foo')

db.execute("INSERT INTO foo(alpha, beta) VALUES ('hello', 'world')")

foo_res      = [dict(r) for r in db.execute('SELECT "f"."alpha", "f"."beta" FROM "foo"      "f"')]
foo_view_res = [dict(r) for r in db.execute('SELECT "f"."alpha", "f"."beta" FROM "foo_view" "f"')]

print(foo_res)
print(foo_view_res)
```

When run, the output looks like the following:

```
[{'alpha': 'hello', 'beta': 'world'}]
[{'f': 'hello'}]
```

In my opinion, those should however result in the exact same dict. What is going on here?

There is also a difference between python3 and python2. When run on python2, the output is as follows:

```
[{'alpha': u'hello', 'beta': u'world'}]
[{'"f"."beta"': u'world', '"f"."alpha"': u'hello'}]
```

Comment: Works in Python 2.7. This looks like a bug when parsing the column names.

Comment: Anyway, column names are not guaranteed when you're not using AS.

Comment: Reproducible both on py3.4 and  py2.7, linux x86. BUT when I cast rows to `list` instead of `dict` I get the expected output: two `['hello', 'world']`

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's an issue. I'll purpose a workaround.

The issue appears to be limited to quoting of the table alias in the select clause. So, without these quotes both queries work in python 3:

```
>>> [dict(r) for r in db.execute("select f.alpha, f.beta from foo f")]
[{'alpha': 'hello', 'beta': 'world'}]
>>> [dict(r) for r in db.execute("select f.alpha, f.beta from foo_view f")]
[{'f.alpha': 'hello', 'f.beta': 'world'}]
```

(Note: the view tacks on the alias unlike the table query.) 
When quotes are added to the table alias in the select clause, things go awry:

```
>>> [dict(r) for r in db.execute("select 'f'.alpha, f.beta from foo_view as f")]
[{'f': 'hello', 'f.beta': 'world'}]
```

If there really are spaces in your table names, you can get away with:

```
>>> [dict(r) for r in db.execute('select f."alpha", f."beta" from foo_view as "f"')]
[{'f."alpha"': 'hello', 'f."beta"': 'world'}]
```

But obviously not with spaces in the table alias, since you'll need to quote them. That said, I think it is poor practice to have spaces in a table's alias name -- and with no spaces in the table alias one can skip quoting the table alias in the select clause.

In brief, the workaround is not to quote your table aliases.